# Error in callback for watcher "$route": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest')"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, router

Sorry for the inconvenience but I hope you can help me.
I use VueJS 2
Friends I am programming in Vuejs and when redirecting from a router-link with the property :to I get the error on the page where it redirects me

```
Error in callback for watcher "$route": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest')"

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'closest') at VueComponent.$route
```

My code where I redirect from

```
<b-dropdown-item :to="{name: 'roles-permissions-edit', params:{id:row.item.id}}" link-class="action-edit">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit-3"><path d="M12 20h9"></path><path d="M16.5 3.5a2.121 2.121 0 0 1 3 3L7 19l-4 1 1-4L16.5 3.5z"></path></svg>
        Editar
</b-dropdown-item>
```

My file in router

```
{
        path: '/settings/roles-permissions/edit/:id',
        name: 'roles-permissions-edit',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "role-permissions-edit" */ '../views/settings/roles-permissions/roles-permissions-edit.vue')
    },
```

I hope you can help me, let me know if you need to see something specific about my code

Comment: Please share the code of the component that you want to navigate to by `roles-permissions-edit` ?

Comment: `<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            info: '',
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.info = this.$route.params.id;
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: @ManuelLeigh I have edited question for better understanding with your comment